# Identifying a notion of integration

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, integration

Let $f$: $I\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a (not necessarily bounded) function on an interval $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $f$ admits a function $F$: $I\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that

(1) $F$ is continuous

(2) $\forall x\in I$: $f$ continuous at $x$ $\Rightarrow$ $F$ differentiable at $x$ with $F'(x)=f(x)$

(3) Up to additive constants, $F$ is unique with the above two properties.

This well-defines a generalized Newton-like integral notion by setting $\int_a^b f:=F(b)-F(a)$

**Questions:** Which functions are integrable in this sense? Is there an integral notion equivalent to this?

Certainly it is necessary for $f$ to be continuous on a dense set of points.

Comment: It is *not* sufficient for $f$ to be Riemann integrable: for example, if $f$ is supported by the Cantor set $C$ and discontinuous at all points of $C$ (so $f=\chi_C$ would work), then it won't satisfy your conditions (uniqueness fails).

Comment: I think ChristianRemling's example of lack of uniqueness can be generalized to any function $f$ with an uncountable set $D$ of discontinuities (In this case, $D$ contains a non-empty perfect set $C$, and there is a non-zero continuous measure supported on $C$, so that $F$, if any, is never unique). On the other hand, if the set of discontinuities of $f$ is at most countable, then certainly any two $F$ differ by a constant. Also, any regulated function $f$ (i.e. having right and left  limits at any point, hence at most countably many discontinuities ) does possess a generalized primitive $F$.